# Magento 2 - Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource after update from 2.4.5 to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I get the following error if I load my homepage, after I upgraded from 2.4.5 to 2.4.5-p1:

```
Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#1 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#2 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
#3 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#4 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
#5 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#6 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
#7 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#8 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#9 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock()
#10 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(252): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance()
#11 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(229): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock()
#12 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(134): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock()
#13 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process()
#14 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(365): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process()
#15 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#16 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/html/company_245/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#19 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#20 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#22 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#23 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(896): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#24 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(216): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock()
#25 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(74): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage()
#26 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#27 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
#28 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/html/company_245/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#30 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#31 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#32 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
#33 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#34 /var/www/html/company_245/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#35 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
#36 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#37 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#38 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#39 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#40 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#41 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#42 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#43 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#44 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#45 /var/www/html/company_245/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#46 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#47 /var/www/html/company_245/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#48 /var/www/html/company_245/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#49 {main}
```

---

I tried:

1. delete vendor folder
2. `composer clearcache`
3. `composer install`
4. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
5. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

But the error is still there.

I even downgraded to 2.4.5 again but I still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when any of our custom or third party extension has default parameter in between for __construct() arguments instead of at the end.

Please check which action you're performing while getting this error. One of the classes involved in this action can have a default parameter in between, like below:

[image]

Need to move `array $data = []` at the last position because it has a default value.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps To Reproduce**

- check the PHP version compatibility with Magento 2.4.5-p1
- Check the Full Logs
- Check any third party extension may conflict with Magento 2.4.5-p1
- First, fix the optional parameter issue that you can have in PHP 8.1 i.e. rearrange the constructor:
  Pass the optional parameters after the required parameters i.e

  my__construct(...., $optional)
- Then, before performing the above steps, I would remove the vendor directory or rename the directory and launch the terminal again and execute the command

  composer install

to regenerate all the Magento standard codes. You can check your vendor folder to make sure laminas are installed and run the compilation command later to load the dependencies.

Comment: I downgraded to 2.4.5 again, but I still get the error...

Comment: Did you Remove Vendor and run the composer update again?

Comment: Yes, I removed vendor again and executed composer install

Comment: The problem is due to one of our own extensions which is not compatible to 2.4.5 anymore.

Comment: Perfect sounds your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to one of our own extensions which used `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource`. We have no clue why the error is thrown though and need to investigate it further.

We disabled the module for now.

Comment: did you find out what the problem was? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after update to 2.4.6 due to extending my custom module's model with `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`. In my case it was due to order of parameters in the model's `__construct` method - it should be custom first and then parent class parameters.

When it looked like this I was getting the error:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
}
```

So I've changed the parameters order and the error went away:

```
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
```